# Deadlock with concurrent SELECT FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED and UPDATE on the result set?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

We have a method that looks like this:

```
@Transactional
public UpdateTestObjsResponse updateTestObjs() {
    objs = repository.findAllReadyTestObjsForOwnerX(); // SELECT ... FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED native query
    LOGGER.info("==DEBUG== RowCount=" + objs.size());
    for (TestObj obj: objs) {
        LOGGER.info("==DEBUG== RowUuid=" + obj.getUuid());
        // ...
        obj.setState('WAITING');
        repository.save(obj);
    }
    return getResponseObj(objs);
}
```

Invoking this method concurrently results in a deadlock being detected for reasons that escape me, and it seems the transaction is committed before the `UPDATE` which is somewhat unexpected to me:

```
{"method":"begin","level":"DEBUG","line":81,"description":"begin","type":"log","@timestamp":"2023-05-17T13:40:44.406314Z","application":"TestApp","correlation_id":"edfc0a80-eeb5-4a4c-856f-8f1432430560","class":"org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl","application_version":"localhost"}
{"method":"begin","level":"DEBUG","line":81,"description":"begin","type":"log","@timestamp":"2023-05-17T13:40:44.406352Z","application":"TestApp","correlation_id":"6169ce79-8cc2-49d3-871a-8156ff96b2c8","class":"org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl","application_version":"localhost"}
"Hibernate: SELECT * FROM TestDb.test_table WHERE owner_uuid = '9f95191b-af31-40c9-b5d8-a3c48e6a69b0' AND state = 'READY' ORDER BY timestamp ASC LIMIT 10 FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED"
"Hibernate: SELECT * FROM TestDb.test_table WHERE owner_uuid = '9f95191b-af31-40c9-b5d8-a3c48e6a69b0' AND state = 'READY' ORDER BY timestamp ASC LIMIT 10 FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED"
{"method":"updateTestObjs","level":"INFO","line":545,"description":"==DEBUG== RowCount=1","type":"log","@timestamp":"2023-05-17T13:40:44.438215Z","application":"TestApp","correlation_id":"6169ce79-8cc2-49d3-871a-8156ff96b2c8","class":"redacted.service.TestService","application_version":"localhost"}
{"method":"updateTestObjs","level":"INFO","line":545,"description":"==DEBUG== RowCount=4","type":"log","@timestamp":"2023-05-17T13:40:44.438205Z","application":"TestApp","correlation_id":"edfc0a80-eeb5-4a4c-856f-8f1432430560","class":"redacted.service.TestService","application_version":"localhost"}
{"method":"updateTestObjs","level":"INFO","line":547,"description":"==DEBUG== RowUuid=3469af18-f55d-408a-9231-e5fbb68c76f8","type":"log","@timestamp":"2023-05-17T13:40:44.438439Z","application":"TestApp","correlation_id":"6169ce79-8cc2-49d3-871a-8156ff96b2c8","class":"redacted.service.TestService","application_version":"localhost"}
{"method":"updateTestObjs","level":"INFO","line":547,"description":"==DEBUG== RowUuid=6338750b-aa50-487d-8e0d-739cd16d9adb","type":"log","@timestamp":"2023-05-17T13:40:44.438459Z","application":"TestApp","correlation_id":"edfc0a80-eeb5-4a4c-856f-8f1432430560","class":"redacted.service.TestService","application_version":"localhost"}
{"method":"updateTestObjs","level":"INFO","line":547,"description":"==DEBUG== RowUuid=d0dda3df-9532-402b-8aab-2ca3d362d032","type":"log","@timestamp":"2023-05-17T13:40:44.446588Z","application":"TestApp","correlation_id":"edfc0a80-eeb5-4a4c-856f-8f1432430560","class":"redacted.service.TestService","application_version":"localhost"}
{"method":"commit","level":"DEBUG","line":98,"description":"committing","type":"log","@timestamp":"2023-05-17T13:40:44.446875Z","application":"TestApp","correlation_id":"6169ce79-8cc2-49d3-871a-8156ff96b2c8","class":"org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl","application_version":"localhost"}
{"method":"updateTestObjs","level":"INFO","line":547,"description":"==DEBUG== RowUuid=fadcbae6-1ce9-46bc-bfe6-1d3c1f88c89b","type":"log","@timestamp":"2023-05-17T13:40:44.446991Z","application":"TestApp","correlation_id":"edfc0a80-eeb5-4a4c-856f-8f1432430560","class":"redacted.service.TestService","application_version":"localhost"}
{"method":"updateTestObjs","level":"INFO","line":547,"description":"==DEBUG== RowUuid=e139e56e-7945-4818-adf1-4de51c4832c8","type":"log","@timestamp":"2023-05-17T13:40:44.447205Z","application":"TestApp","correlation_id":"edfc0a80-eeb5-4a4c-856f-8f1432430560","class":"redacted.service.TestService","application_version":"localhost"}
{"method":"commit","level":"DEBUG","line":98,"description":"committing","type":"log","@timestamp":"2023-05-17T13:40:44.447403Z","application":"TestApp","correlation_id":"edfc0a80-eeb5-4a4c-856f-8f1432430560","class":"org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl","application_version":"localhost"}
"Hibernate: update test_table set owner_uuid=?, state=?, timestamp=?, where obj_uuid=?"
"Hibernate: update test_table set owner_uuid=?, state=?, timestamp=?, where obj_uuid=?"
{"method":"logExceptions","level":"WARN","line":137,"description":"SQL Error: 1213, SQLState: 40001","type":"log","@timestamp":"2023-05-17T13:40:44.472873Z","application":"TestApp","correlation_id":"edfc0a80-eeb5-4a4c-856f-8f1432430560","class":"org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper","application_version":"localhost"}
{"method":"logExceptions","level":"ERROR","line":142,"description":"Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction","type":"log","@timestamp":"2023-05-17T13:40:44.473116Z","application":"TestApp","correlation_id":"edfc0a80-eeb5-4a4c-856f-8f1432430560","class":"org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper","application_version":"localhost"}
{"method":"rollback","level":"DEBUG","line":131,"description":"rollback() called on an inactive transaction","type":"log","@timestamp":"2023-05-17T13:40:44.478103Z","application":"TestApp","correlation_id":"edfc0a80-eeb5-4a4c-856f-8f1432430560","class":"org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl","application_version":"localhost"}
""
```

Here, `updateTestObjs` is annotated with `@Transacational` from `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional` and declared as a public method in the service, being called from the controller, to which two requests are made in parallel, resulting in the logs above. I verified the database engine is InnoDB, which supports transactions and the `FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED` directives. Furthermore, I'm not overwriting the default isolation level, so I'd expect Spring to use InnoDB's default of `READ_COMMITTED`. This is to say I've checked some common pitfalls reported in other questions.

I've tried manually managing the transaction as such to see what happens:

```
    @Autowired
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;

    @Autowired
    private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;


public UpdateTestObjsResponse updateTestObjs() {
    var transactionTemplate = new TransactionTemplate(transactionManager);
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
    tx.begin();
    try {
        Query sel = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM TestDb.test_table WHERE owner_uuid = '9f95191b-af31-40c9-b5d8-a3c48e6a69b0' AND state = 'READY' ORDER BY timestamp ASC LIMIT 10 FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED", TestObj.class);
        transactionTemplate.execute(
            status -> {
                List<TestObj> objs = sel.getResultList();
                LOGGER.info("==DEBUG== RowCount=" + objs.size());
                for (TestObj obj : objs) {
                    LOGGER.info("==DEBUG== RowUuid=" + obj.getUuid());
                    Query upd = em.createNativeQuery("UPDATE TestDb.test_table SET state = 'WAITING' WHERE obj_uuid = ?");
                    upd.setParameter(1, obj.getUuid());
                    upd.executeUpdate();
                }
                return objs.size();
            });
        tx.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        tx.rollback();
        LOGGER.error(e);
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
    return getResponseObj(objs);
}
```

This avoids the transaction being commited before the `UPDATE`, but also results in a deadlock. For completeness, here are the logs:

```
{"method":"begin","level":"DEBUG","line":81,"description":"begin","type":"log","@timestamp":"2023-05-17T12:44:07.055847Z","application":"TestApp","correlation_id":"5e0d8e88-2316-422b-a690-a625b4352a1e","class":"org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl","application_version":"localhost"}
{"method":"begin","level":"DEBUG","line":81,"description":"begin","type":"log","@timestamp":"2023-05-17T12:44:07.055917Z","application":"TestApp","correlation_id":"ab18ea56-942b-4e5f-9134-037bdf2d25c0","class":"org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl","application_version":"localhost"}
"Hibernate: SELECT * FROM TestDb.test_table WHERE owner_uuid = '9f95191b-af31-40c9-b5d8-a3c48e6a69b0' AND state = 'READY' ORDER BY timestamp ASC LIMIT 10 FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED"
"Hibernate: SELECT * FROM TestDb.test_table WHERE owner_uuid = '9f95191b-af31-40c9-b5d8-a3c48e6a69b0' AND state = 'READY' ORDER BY timestamp ASC LIMIT 10 FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED"
{"method":"lambda$updateTestObjs$2","level":"INFO","line":553,"description":"==DEBUG== RowCount=1","type":"log","@timestamp":"2023-05-17T12:44:07.073758Z","application":"TestApp","correlation_id":"ab18ea56-942b-4e5f-9134-037bdf2d25c0","class":"redacted.service.TestService","application_version":"localhost"}
{"method":"lambda$updateTestObjs$2","level":"INFO","line":553,"description":"==DEBUG== RowCount=4","type":"log","@timestamp":"2023-05-17T12:44:07.073758Z","application":"TestApp","correlation_id":"5e0d8e88-2316-422b-a690-a625b4352a1e","class":"redacted.service.TestService","application_version":"localhost"}
{"method":"lambda$updateTestObjs$2","level":"INFO","line":555,"description":"==DEBUG== RowUuid=e139e56e-7945-4818-adf1-4de51c4832c8","type":"log","@timestamp":"2023-05-17T12:44:07.073985Z","application":"TestApp","correlation_id":"ab18ea56-942b-4e5f-9134-037bdf2d25c0","class":"redacted.service.TestService","application_version":"localhost"}
{"method":"lambda$updateTestObjs$2","level":"INFO","line":555,"description":"==DEBUG== RowUuid=6338750b-aa50-487d-8e0d-739cd16d9adb","type":"log","@timestamp":"2023-05-17T12:44:07.073990Z","application":"TestApp","correlation_id":"5e0d8e88-2316-422b-a690-a625b4352a1e","class":"redacted.service.TestService","application_version":"localhost"}
"Hibernate: UPDATE TestDb.test_table SET state = 'WAITING' WHERE obj_uuid = ?"
"Hibernate: UPDATE TestDb.test_table SET state = 'WAITING' WHERE obj_uuid = ?"
{"method":"lambda$updateTestObjs$2","level":"INFO","line":555,"description":"==DEBUG== RowUuid=d0dda3df-9532-402b-8aab-2ca3d362d032","type":"log","@timestamp":"2023-05-17T12:44:07.083935Z","application":"TestApp","correlation_id":"5e0d8e88-2316-422b-a690-a625b4352a1e","class":"redacted.service.TestService","application_version":"localhost"}
"Hibernate: UPDATE TestDb.test_table SET state = 'WAITING' WHERE obj_uuid = ?"
{"method":"lambda$updateTestObjs$2","level":"INFO","line":555,"description":"==DEBUG== RowUuid=3469af18-f55d-408a-9231-e5fbb68c76f8","type":"log","@timestamp":"2023-05-17T12:44:07.087683Z","application":"TestApp","correlation_id":"5e0d8e88-2316-422b-a690-a625b4352a1e","class":"redacted.service.TestService","application_version":"localhost"}
{"method":"logExceptions","level":"WARN","line":137,"description":"SQL Error: 1213, SQLState: 40001","type":"log","@timestamp":"2023-05-17T12:44:07.087787Z","application":"TestApp","correlation_id":"ab18ea56-942b-4e5f-9134-037bdf2d25c0","class":"org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper","application_version":"localhost"}
```

Finally, if I do not use `FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED` in the original code, no deadlock occurs but overlapping objects are selected by both method calls, which is undesirable:

```
"Hibernate: SELECT * FROM TestDb.test_table WHERE owner_uuid = '9f95191b-af31-40c9-b5d8-a3c48e6a69b0' AND state = 'READY' ORDER BY timestamp ASC LIMIT 10 FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED"
"Hibernate: SELECT * FROM TestDb.test_table WHERE owner_uuid = '9f95191b-af31-40c9-b5d8-a3c48e6a69b0' AND state = 'READY' ORDER BY timestamp ASC LIMIT 10 FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED"
{"method":"updateTestObjs","level":"INFO","line":544,"description":"==DEBUG== RowCount=5","type":"log","@timestamp":"2023-05-17T13:39:13.235097Z","application":"TestApp","correlation_id":"4651077f-076f-49e0-a4cb-06d3cc575993","class":"redacted.service.TestService","application_version":"localhost"}
{"method":"updateTestObjs","level":"INFO","line":544,"description":"==DEBUG== RowCount=5","type":"log","@timestamp":"2023-05-17T13:39:13.235097Z","application":"TestApp","correlation_id":"6d0f3cf1-d75f-4502-b577-b8efc0871f72","class":"redacted.service.TestService","application_version":"localhost"}
```

Regardless of this implementation being suitable or not when parallel requests are to be expected, why is a deadlock detected with `FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED`?

Comment: what does the TestDb.test_table look like exactly? Do you have other constraints on the fields you are modifying? Something as simple as modifying a value used as the target of a foreign key in another table can cause table locks outside of where you are looking. Most DBs have mechanisms to show what is holding onto which locks.

Comment: @Chris It's fairly simple - no foreign keys, the primary key is the aforementioned uuid which is `VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL`, other columns are also `VARCHAR`, `INTEGER`, and `TIMESTAMP`. No manually created indices. I'll see if I can get information on the locks when the deadlock is detected.

Comment: @Chris Unlike I previously thought, there is indeed an index in that table... Precisely on the column being updated (`state`). I've used `show engine innodb status` and it has details on which locks were held and which locks were waited on during the deadlock. It seems like both transactions somehow held an insert intention X lock on the index? I don't understand. I've pasted the output [here](https://pastebin.com/raw/p4L9wmLu), but I can create a new question (maybe on another StackExchange site) if you think it's best.

Comment: Locks involving indexes and constraints strains what I know, so a separate, more specific question now that you know the root cause is probably best. The answer here is that everything IS working by design because your actual update is requiring a more general lock on a specific index that all your transactions and updates on this table seem to need to lock. How to get around that - you'd need to show the index for a good solution and hopefully a MySQL expert might help, but simplest hack is just to remove the index - I don't know how many states you've, but seems overly general anyway.

Answer (score -1):

To avoid long waiting transactions you can break data fetch and saving part in to 2 methods and limit the transaction duration to save single object. It can reduce deadlock chances.

```
class Service {

        @Autowired
        private Repository dao;

        // Not Transactional
        public List<?> UpdateAndReturn() {
         
          //marked @Transactional(value = TxType.SUPPORTS) or no tansaction.
          List<?> objs  = dao.readAll();
          
          for(Obj obj:objs) {
              //marked @Transactional(value = TxType.REQUIRED)
              Obj o = dao.getById(obj.getId());
              //  modifications
              //marked @Transactional(value = TxType.REQUIRED)
              dao.save(o);
          }
          return objs;
         }
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).